# Pluck or Something else?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

DB::table('mobil')->where('id',$id)->first().

I ever try it, but it give me all columns data. The problem is, In this Mobil table I have name, status, des, model and Id. The data that I need is name, status, and des. Can you help me to make a code to take some data that I need and it must one row. It must first row

Answer (score 2):

you can use `select` method

```
DB::table('mobil')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->select(['name', 'status', 'des'])
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DB query

```
DB::table('mobil')
    ->select('name', 'status', 'des')
    ->where('id', $id)  
    ->first();
```

Using model

if your model is Mobil.php

```
Mobil::select('name', 'status', 'des')
    ->where('id', $id)  
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass columns name as array in `->first()` method

```
DB::table('mobil')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->first(['name', 'status', 'des'])
```